# Is there a single word for "Parts of Speech"?

Tags: single-word-requests, parts-of-speech

Is there a word that refers to the different **forms** of a word, or a word's following four **parts of speech**—verb, adverb, noun, adjective?

For example:

> confuse *verb* 
> confusedly *adverb* 
> confusion *noun* 
> confused, confusing, & confusable *adjective*

What word should be inserted if I wanted to say: 
"I'm looking for all the [**forms/parts of speech**] of confuse." 
or 
"I want to use a [**form/part of speech**] of *startle* that is not in the dictionary; *bestartlement*, for example."

I think the answer to my question might be here [Word form dictionary/system/tool](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131668/word-form-dictionary-system-tool), but I couldn't understand the descriptions of ***Inflection*** and ***Conjugation*** well enough to be certain that either is the word I am looking for.

EDIT:
After reading through the links on [*declensions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension) and [*derivational morphology*](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Inflection.pdf) provided by Benjamin Harman and John Lawler respectively, I agree with Lawler that declensions are not what I am talking about. I think I want to refer to the set of any given content word's semantically associated parts of speech, i.e. all the various derivational morpheme altered forms of a given content word (and sometimes to just *one* of a content word's corresponding forms in a different lexical category).
All these terms are new to me, so I apologize if I used any of them incorrectly.

Comment: **Speechparts**.

Comment: Have you banned prepositions, coordinators, complementisers, interjections, determiners, particles ... (depending on school adhered to)? And if a candidate is not in any dictionary, it's presumptuous to call it a word.

Comment: No, there's no single word. _Lexical categories_ is a technical term used by grammarians; it means different kinds of words as used in any language, not just Latin or English. There are quite a few, and every language has a different assortment, organized in different ways. "Parts of speech" is the English translation of [_partes orationis_, which is what the Latin grammarians](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html) called those categories they knew about, in Latin. They missed some.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, given the constant susceptibility of language to change (provided it is not a dead language), if an assortment of letters presents a single meaning that is understood by a given audience or by the predominance of a given language's current literate demographic, isn't it presumptuous to say that this group of letters is *not* a word simply because it is not listed in a dictionary?

Comment: Could 'derivation' do the job you're looking for?

Comment: What is wrong with *forms*? As far as I know, that is the term that refers to this.

Comment: @Karl yes, I think 'derivation' is satisfactory. I used to use 'conjugation' before I learned how that is a misapplication.

Comment: Yes, @Peter, a misuse, but a common one.

Answer (score -1):

Different variations of a non-verb word by parts of speech, by syntactic function, are called "declensions," so "confusedly" is the adverbial declension, "confusion" is the nounal declension, "confused" an adjectival declension. Another word used is "case," like "happy," "happily," and "happiness" are all different cases (i.e., adjective, adverb, and noun, respectively).

When the word is a verb, the variations are called "conjugations."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension

Comment: _Conjugation_ and _declension_ are only for paradigmatic affixes, not all variation. Latin (and English) adverbs don't have declensions

Comment: "Declensions may apply to nouns, pronouns, adjectives, **adverbs**, and articles to indicate number (e.g. singular, dual, plural), case (e.g. nominative case, accusative case, genitive case, dative case), gender (e.g. masculine, neuter, feminine), and a number of other grammatical categories. [**bold** added for emphasis]." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension)

Comment: Yes, they **may**. In some languages. But for variations to be declensions or conjugations, they have to be paradigmatic  -- i.e, the variation has to occur in systematic paradigms, like German cases or Swahili genders. If a feature has no paradigms, like (say) Mandarin nouns or English adjectives, then their variations aren't declensions. I think you may be confusing _declension_ with [inflectional or derivational morphology](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf). 'Conjugation' and 'declension' are two special terms for inflections; that's all.

Comment: 'Telescope' (verb) is an 'intercategorial polyseme' of the original (in English) noun formed by 'zero derivation' / 'null derivation', not declension or conjugation.

Comment: Yep. Derivational morphology like Zero or _-ation_ is non-paradigmatic and declensions or conjugations aren't discussed in their context for that reason.

Comment: I still don't quite understand *paradigmatic* and *non-paradigmatic*.

Comment: Conjugations and declensions are paradigms; usually they're displayed as tables, like [this exercise](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Paradigm.pdf) from an introductory class. Any morphology (prefixes, suffixes, vowel changes, etc) that can be displayed in a table, like a spreadsheet, is paradigmatic. Other stuff that's sporadic and unpredictable is non-paradigmatic. (btw, there are two typos in the Latin paradigm on the exercise. *Sigh*)

Comment: ... Aw, Caesar.